# MvvmCross: Application wide view model?

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am loving MvvmCross so far, but I am new to the MVVM technique.  MVVM seems to center around the View and ViewModel and navigating between them.  However, what about application-wide model items?  Maybe my application has a mode that it can be in that affects all views and viewmodel behavior.  This seems like an ApplicationModel or ApplicationViewModel.  Or maybe just use the App class itself to store application wide stuff?  What is the recommended practice for this concept?  If using the App class itself is a good idea, I assume there is an easy way to get a hold of the reference to the App instance from anywhere?  Haven't looked yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ViewModel` is a Model for a View - so that's where the current MvvmCross focus sits.

For this application wide behaviour, I think it's best to consider it one use case at a time.

The example you've provided is:

> Maybe my application has a mode that it can be in that affects all views and viewmodel behavior.

There's not much detail here, but for this type of thing I might perhaps:

- place this `Mode` inside a `Singleton` service
- would use a messenger to send `ModeChangedMessage`s when the `Mode` changed
- would provide that service and the messenger to the relevant ViewModels using constructor injection
- the ViewModels can then subscribe for `ModeChangedMessage` on the messenger
- would perhaps use inheritance in my ViewModels to share code between them (ie they'd inherit from a `BaseViewModel` class)

There are of course other ways to do this, but that's one suggestion

---

If there's some other application wide use case you'd like to ask about, please ask another question - but please include more detail - eg perhaps provide some pseudo-code about what you want to share. I find real use cases easier to work out - abstract ideas are harder to talk about.

---

If it helps:

- There's an introduction to services and constructor injection in N=2 on http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com
- There's an introduction to the Messenger on N=9 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com